# How to trigger rendered of h:panelgroup when i click commandbutton with f:ajax

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

Hi guys there is a commandbutton and panelgroup below. When the page is loaded panelgroup is hide. So far so good. But After that, How to show panelgorup when I click commandButton ?

```
<h:form>     
    <h:commandButton  value="Kitap" >
       <f:ajax id="input1" render="output" event="click"  listener="#{admin.getSatis}" />


     </h:commandButton>     
</h:form> 

<h:panelGroup rendered="false"  id="output" >

                        <h:dataTable  value="#{admin.list}" var="o">


                            <h:column>
                                    <f:facet  name="header">İsim</f:facet>
                                    #{o.isim}
                            </h:column>

                            <h:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">Soyisim</f:facet>
                                    #{o.soyisim}
                            </h:column>


                        </h:dataTable>

                     </h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't show a component that is not rendered. You need to wrap it and refresh its parent.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton id="input1" value="Kitap" >
        <f:ajax render=":output-wrapper" listener="#{admin.getSatis}" />
    </h:commandButton>     
</h:form> 

<h:panelGroup id="output-wrapper">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.someCondition}" id="output" >
        <h:dataTable  value="#{admin.list}" var="o">
            <h:column>
                    <f:facet  name="header">İsim</f:facet>
                    #{o.isim}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Soyisim</f:facet>
                    #{o.soyisim}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Initialise your `myBean` with `someCondition` to `false`. In `admin.getSatis`, set `someCondition` to `true`.

Answer (score -2):

On h:commandButton update(update=":output") attribute update the 'output'.